# VSCode debug controls positioned out of editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidently positioned the debug controls outside the editor's bounds.Now every time I open that project, it comes like that

[image: debug controls moved out of editor's bounds]

debug controls moved out of editor's bounds

Comment: Would appreciate it if you file this as a bug on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: Done. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these settings get cached, I fiddled around for an hour. I ended up deleting the folder

> ~/Library/Application Support/Code

If you want to **retain your VSCode preferences(snippets,shortcuts etc.)** though, delete only:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Code/Local Storage